# remove first ocurrence data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe

So I've been playing around with a data frame in R, although I'm still thinking too much in Python and cannot seem to find a solution for my problem.

I have a data frame and one of the column is an user id. I would like to remove all the first occurrence of a number, for instance:

```
1,2,3,4,3,4,2,1,3,4,6,7,7
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
 3,4,2,1,3,4,7
```

Where the first time the user_id appears I would remove it but keep all the others even if repeated.

With python I would probably use enumerate or loop over it. For R, I've seen some functions that seem cool but I'm not sure how to use it with the data frame, like rle.

Any pointers will be really helpful since right now I'm a bit lost about the best approach for this problem.

Thank you all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `duplicated()` is going to be helpful here:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,3,4,2,1,3,4,6,7,7)
> x[duplicated(x)]
[1] 3 4 2 1 3 4 7
```

---

This works because `duplicated()` returns a logical vector indicating whether that element is, well, duplicated:

```
duplicated(x)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

You then use this logical vector to subset (extract) the values you want from x. But notice that in the extraction I **keep** all of the duplicated values, not remove them.

To remove all of the duplicated values (not what you want, but I illustrate regardless), try the negation:

```
x[!duplicated(x)]
[1] 1 2 3 4 6 7
```

Comment: but duplicated is suppose to remove all duplicates except one for what I understood

Comment: @pavid Yes, but notice that I **keep** all of the duplicated elements.  This works, as far as I can tell, even if I add many more duplicated values to your sample data.

Comment: ok, I'm a bit confused because I've use before duplicated to keep only one row and apparently it also work like this..

Comment: @pavid Ahah. Perhaps that's because you used `duplicated` on a data frame. Notice that I use it on a vector.

Comment: perfect! Actually that was what I've done, to remove all! but it didn't even occurred to try without the negation :s Thank you! :)

Comment: but I want to do this in a data frame.. the example with duplicated does not work in a data frame?